# How does power bi visual adjust when window is resized?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Does power bi visual dynamically adjust when the iframe is resized?  That is does the graph change it's layout to adjust to how much information can be show based on the size of the iframe?

For example, let's say you have a key/legend on the right side of the graph.  As you resize the iframe and shrink the width, will the key/legend re-adjust to the bottom of the graph instead of being on the right side of the graph.  Or perhaps show less data points?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 0):

This answer has 2 parts:

1. When assigned a certain size, a visual (and any other Power BI entity) computes its optimal display setting, e.g. number of data points, legend location and visibility of certain elements.
   Given the default size, or a custom one using 'Custom Layout' options (https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Custom-Layout), you can control the size of the desired element.
2. As for resize, you can control the size of the element inside the iframe, like you would control the iframe's size. some features listen on the iframe's 'onResize' but most would require the develeoper to set a new size, via 'updateSettings' with the new size.

```js
var visual = powerbi.embed(embedIframe, config); // the visual embed startup

$(embedIframe).resize(function () {
  var width = $(embedIframe).width();
  var height = $(embedIframe).height();
  
  var newSettings = {
    // Settings accounting for custom layout with new size
  };
  visual.updateSettings(newSettings);
});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: powerbi is not defined. How to resolve it?